# How to set visibility of Android compound view via databinding in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have checked many answers to find my issue however I was not successful. I have an activity that holds a compound drawable.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.my.profile.widgets.ProfileWidget
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    ....
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

This is my ProfileWidget:

```
  class ProfileWidget @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context,
                                                  attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
                                                  defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

        @Inject lateinit var viewModel: ProfileWidgetViewData
        @Inject lateinit var viewActions: ProfileWidgetActions

        private val binding: WidgetProfileBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.widget_profile, this, true)
    //    private val binding = WidgetProfileBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)

        override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow()
            setupDependencyInjection()
            setupDataBinding()

            viewActions.testUI()
        }

        private fun setupDependencyInjection() {
            (context as ProfileActivity).getProfileComponent()?.inject(this)
        }

        private fun setupDataBinding() {
            binding.viewModel = viewModel
        }
    }
```

This is its layout:

```
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>
            <import type="android.view.View" />

            <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="com.my.profile.widgets.ProfileWidgetViewData" />
        </data>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profilesContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="profile 1"
                android:visibility="@{viewModel.textView_1.get() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="profile 2"
                android:visibility="@{viewModel.textView_2.get() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </layout>
```

Finally my ViewModel class supposed to make TextViews
 visible/invisible.

```
 interface ProfileWidgetViewData {
        val textView_1: ObservableBoolean
        val textView_2: ObservableBoolean
    }

    interface ProfileWidgetActions {
        fun testUI()
    }

    class ProfileWidgetViewModelImpl : ProfileWidgetViewData, ProfileWidgetActions {

        override val textView_1 = ObservableBoolean(false)
        override val textView_2 = ObservableBoolean(false)

        override fun testUI() {
            setProfilesContainerVisibility(true)
            setAddProfileContainerVisibility(true)
        }

        private fun setProfilesContainerVisibility(isVisible: Boolean) {
            textView_1.set(isVisible)
        }

        private fun setAddProfileContainerVisibility(isVisible: Boolean) {
            textView_2.set(isVisible)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I don't see anything wrong in above codes. When I launch
the app, those two TextView are Invisible although I have set them to be visible.

Comment: Use the field directly without calling get() on it, just *viewModel.textView_1* for example.

Comment: @PrateekBhardwaj: thanks for wanting to edit and improve questions here. However, please do not use quote blocks for the titles of code - they are not themselves quotes. Quotes have a special semantic meaning, which is that they were spoken or written elsewhere, e.g. a speech, a book, a manual, a website, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check below is added or not in build.gradle(obviously you already added)

```
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    android {
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }     
    }
    dependencies {
       kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.3"
    }
```

And add below line in your xml file for visibility or invisible

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="profile 1"
        android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.textView_1) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Shweta for your answer. I didn't know `safeUnbox` and even related warning's gone by using this method. However, I still don't see TextViews. I confirm I have those gradle lines. So, in this case, let me enable/disable Views in old way to see does it work or still not working. I'll update my question.